# Determining max shear stress

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, structural-analysis, torque, shear

So I understand that shear stress can be either in the the form of transverse or torsional or both at the same time.  And normal stress is due to the moment or a force normal to the surface. My question is why is it that sometimes when it asks for the max shear stress we use the $\tau_{max}= \sqrt{\left( \frac{\sigma}{2}\right)^2 + \tau^2}$ and sometimes we use $\tau_{max} = \tau_v + \tau_T$  to find the max shear stress?

Why sometimes do we consider the normal stress in calculating the max shear stress and sometimes we do not?

[[image: This is an example where it says find the max shear stress and we use <span class=]$\tau_{max}= \tau_v + \tau_T$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Litwk.png)

Comment: I am not certain the notation you are using for $\tau_{max} = \tau_v + \tau_T$. What is $\tau_v$ and what is $\tau_T$?

Comment: Additionally, does your question regarding the $\tau_{max}= \sqrt{\left( \frac{\sigma}{2}\right)^2 + \tau^2}$ refers mainly to the Mohr's circle? Because a similar expression is also encountered at failure theories.

Comment: @NMech tV is the transverse shear stress and tT is the torsional shear stress

Comment: IMHO, I think you should provide at least one (maybe two) concrete examples, in order to answer that efficiently (because this can have a multitude of answers). E.g. in the general case $\tau_{max} = \tau_v + \tau_T$ is not correct. The more general form would be $\tau_{max} = \sqrt{\tau_v^2 + \tau_T^2}$.

Comment: @NMech I edited my question with an example from our lecture. That is one step of the problem and we found max shear stress by tV + tT as shown in the picture but in just a few steps we considered the stress at point A and the max shear stress formula we used was the square root one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you are presenting the shear stresses on cross-section of beam AB are as in the image below.

[image]

- with $\color{green}{green}$ is the shear stress $\tau_v$ which has a single direction (parallel to the shear force)
- with $\color{red}{red}$ is the torsional stress $\tau_T$, which has a changing direction (see the following graph)

[image]

if you notice at points

- B and D the stresses are perpendicular. In that case $\tau=\sqrt{\tau_v^2 +\tau_t^2}$
- C the stresses are cancelling each other. In that case $\tau_C=\tau_v - \tau_t$
- A the stresses are contributing to each other. In that case $\tau_C=\tau_v +  \tau_t$

Now, regarding the other question of your post (i.e. $\tau_{max}= \sqrt{\left( \frac{\sigma}{2}\right)^2 + \tau^2}$), again its best if you post an example you have in mind.

Comment: I couldn't be any more appreciative of your help and your effort. Thank you very much.